# Running Gatling without interactive options

Tags: performance, performance-testing, gatling, vagrant-gatling-rsync

When I run [Gatling](http://gatling.io) (the performance test tool), it always gives me an interactive dialog to run one Scala simulation file at a time. Is there a way to tell Gatling to run all the files in a particular order? I'm sure there must be one, but just don't seem to find a way to specify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you just have to force the simulation with the [appropriate option](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Configuration#cli-options) (-s or -sc depending on the Gatling version you use).

Answer (score 5):

Running

```
user@host $ ./bin/gatling.sh -h
```

returns

```
GATLING_HOME is set to /path/to/gatling
Usage: compiler [options]

  -h, --help               
  -sf, --simulations-folder <value>

  -bf, --binaries-folder <value>

  -ccp, --compilerClasspath <value>

Usage: gatling [options]

  -h, --help               Show help (this message) and exit
  -nr, --no-reports        Runs simulation but does not generate reports
  -m, --mute               Runs in mute mode: doesn't ask for run description or simulation ID, uses defaults
  -ro, --reports-only <directoryName>
                           Generates the reports for the simulation in <directoryName>
  -df, --data-folder <directoryPath>
                           Uses <directoryPath> as the absolute path of the directory where feeders are stored
  -rf, --results-folder <directoryPath>
                           Uses <directoryPath> as the absolute path of the directory where results are stored
  -bdf, --bodies-folder <directoryPath>
                           Uses <directoryPath> as the absolute path of the directory where bodies are stored
  -sf, --simulations-folder <directoryPath>
                           Uses <directoryPath> to discover simulations that could be run
  -bf, --binaries-folder <directoryPath>
                           Uses <directoryPath> as the absolute path of the directory where Gatling should produce compiled binaries
  -s, --simulation <className>
                           Runs <className> simulation
  -on, --output-name <name>
                           Use <name> for the base name of the output directory
  -rd, --run-description <description>
                           A short <description> of the run to include in the report
```

and running

```
./bin/gatling.sh -s RecordedSimulation
```

runs the test in nointeractive mode